# Composer does not install

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I am trying running laravel in my computer, but I have some difficults to install this resource in my machine, follow below a little bit of error in terminal of linux

> All settings correct for using Composer
>   Downloading...
>   Could not create file /var/www/html/composer.phar: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   Download failed: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   Downloading...
>   Could not create file /var/www/html/composer.phar: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   Download failed: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   Downloading...
>   Could not create file /var/www/html/composer.phar: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   Download failed: fopen(/var/www/html/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission denied
>   fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
>   The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
>   alexander@alexander:/var/www/html$

Comment: use your commands as super-admin..

Comment: I use the before the command sudo, but the code returns the same problem

Comment: Did you use `sudo su` before run the command?

Comment: alexander@alexander:/var/www/html$ sudo su curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
Nenhuma entrada de passwd para usuário 'curl'
alexander@alexander:/var/www/html$

Comment: When you pipe you need to add sudo to both commands. So the second part after | should also be sudo

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but I need to use sudo su to run everithing in this path

Comment: @Alexander, You've asked a lot of questions and never marked any as correct? Theres a green tick next to all answers that you are meant to select to help others. Heres a helpful link for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 106):

I used sudo as follows:

sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php

Comment: Thanks you! I wasn't aware of the 2nd "sudo". This should be marked as correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Permission problem troubleshooting:

## Sudo

As g-newa suggested, often the issue lies in you not using `sudo` which allows you to run as root. Please note that just because you put two commands on the same line doesn't mean that you have one command. When you pipe - aka `sudo find -name foo | xargs rm -rf` - you actually have two commands: `find`, and `xargs`. The above will not work. In fact, so long as you have privileges to `find` or, in your case, `curl`, in a folder, you don't even need `sudo` there. Instead, `find -name foo | sudo xargs rm -rf` would be far more likely to work without a hitch. For cases where `sudo` is needed for both commands, simply add it to both commands.

## Permissions

Although less commonly an issue, there are times where a file is on such lock-down that not even a sudoer can touch it. In this instance make sure you understand what the file is and why it is so locked down. Chances are good you should not mess with it. If, however, the settings are restricted as an accident, you can change them to allow root manipulation.

```
ls -la
```

Checks permissions.

```
sudo chmod 700 <filename>
```

Changes permissions to allow for `sudo`.

Answer (score 2):

you should download the file composer.phar in a directroy with permissions. If you don't want, you should run with sudo

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow three simple steps as it describer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-ubuntu-14-04)
You should run all commands trough CLI (command line interface, same Terminal)

1. update package cache: `sudo apt-get update`
2. install dependences: `sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git`
3. download and install composer: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer`
4. to test composer just run `composer`

Voila! Everything is done.